# How to change languages in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, user-controls

I would like to change languages on a SharePoint page. I have already translated the page to different languages, and I would like to swap between them by a button selection (or similar technique).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change an existing site, site collection, or web page from one language to another by applying different language-specific site templates. After you use a language-specific site template for a site or a site collection, the site or site collection always displays content in the language of the original site template.

If you want to change the language of particular page than you can add a [**this WebPart**](https://spbingwebpart.codeplex.com/) on the page.

I haven't tried this but i am sure it will help you. If you need more help than please let me know.

Comment: Is the webpart which i had mentioned in answer helped you to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to apply the SharePoint "variation label". This technique allows sharepoint to "duplicate" sites in many languages.

Basically, lets suppose you created a EN-US site, and want it to be in ES-ES.
When you create a page into your EN site, sharepoint automatically will create the same page into the ES-ES site... and alert you to "translate" the content, making the site work in 2 languages.

To swap between them, you can simple setup a basic JS redirect stuff.

[Here is a nice example of Variation Label setup.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_quick_reads/archive/2013/08/12/sharepoint-2013-variations-creating-site-and-variation-labels.aspx)

Edit: Remeber that you need to have Language Packs installed to be able to use Variation Label.